# simple scrollable textArea in java swing

Tags: java, swing

im learning swing i wrote a code to show simple text Area in jpanel but there is only panel shows not the text Area .

main frame class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

private TextPanel textPanel;
private JButton button;

public MainFrame(){

    super("Hello World!");
    this.textPanel = new TextPanel();
    this.button = new JButton("Click me");

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.add(textPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 500);
    this.setVisible(true);

}

private void add(TextPanel textPanel2, String center) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
};
}
```

and the second class that contain the panel and the text area is

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class TextPanel extends JPanel {

private JTextArea textArea;

public TextPanel() {


    textArea = new JTextArea();

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    add(new JScrollPane(textArea),BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
}
```

[image]

but there is no text area just the panel , also there is no errors in console 
im using java 7 , so what is wrong with my code .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this method which is overriding Container's [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) method

```
private void add(TextPanel textPanel2, String center) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
};
```

Seems like `TextPanel` is not giving any new functionality. Why not just add the `JScrollPane` component directly to the frame?

Comment: thanks i didn't saw this method generated by eclipse